# function pointers and dll load order

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using function pointers and LoadLibrary. Following is the my code. When I added `EvtExportLog` after `_EvtSubscribe` call, it started corrupting `_EvtSubscribe` values, If i added it before as done in following code everything works fine, now When I add another function pointer I am facing the same problem, anybody know what could be the issue here.

```
     HMODULE module = LoadLibrary(L"wevtapi.dll");
    _EvtExportLog             = (BOOL (WINAPI * )(EVT_HANDLE ,LPCWSTR ,LPCWSTR ,LPCWSTR ,DWORD ))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtExportLog");
    _EvtClearLog              = (BOOL (WINAPI * )(EVT_HANDLE ,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,DWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtClearLog");
    _EvtOpenLog               = (EVT_HANDLE  (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE ,LPCWSTR ,DWORD ))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtOpenLog");
    _EvtGetLogInfo            = (BOOL (WINAPI * )( EVT_HANDLE, EVT_LOG_PROPERTY_ID, DWORD, PEVT_VARIANT ,PDWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtGetLogInfo");
    _EvtQuery                 = (EVT_HANDLE (WINAPI * )(EVT_HANDLE,LPCWSTR ,LPCWSTR ,DWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtQuery");
    _EvtNext                  = (BOOL (WINAPI * )(EVT_HANDLE ,DWORD,EVT_HANDLE*,DWORD,DWORD,PDWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtNext");
    _EvtClose                 = (BOOL (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtClose");
    _EvtCreateRenderContext   = (EVT_HANDLE (WINAPI *)(DWORD, LPCWSTR *, DWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtCreateRenderContext");
    _EvtFormatMessage         = (BOOL (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE, EVT_HANDLE, DWORD, DWORD, PEVT_VARIANT, DWORD, DWORD, LPWSTR, PDWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtFormatMessage");
    _EvtOpenPublisherMetadata = (EVT_HANDLE (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LCID, DWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtOpenPublisherMetadata");
    _EvtRender                = (BOOL (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE, EVT_HANDLE, DWORD, DWORD, PVOID, PDWORD, PDWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtRender");
    _EvtSubscribe             = (EVT_HANDLE (WINAPI *)(EVT_HANDLE, HANDLE, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, EVT_HANDLE, PVOID, EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK, DWORD))GetProcAddress(module, "EvtSubscribe");
```

Comment: The issue is probably not related to the order. If the issue is related to this code at all, it's most likely that your function signatures are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DLL Load order, you're trashing the stack somewhere else, and it just happens that _EvtSubscribe is the victim depending on how you order the objects on the stack. The easiest way to trash the stack is if you were calling a function with the wrong signature, possibly by transcribing them by hand instead of just using static linking and the header.